# Why does my 2D array have such strange behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

**EDIT:** The code has been updated based on one of the answers, but still gives the same problem.
I have recently run into the problem with multi-dimensional arrays in C and passing them as arguments. I am using an array of pointers to simulate multidimensional arrays. Each pointer in the array points to another array that contains the values in a row.
I created a struct for matrices that contains the array of pointers and the number of rows and columns. The array of pointers is really just a pointer to a pointer. I have found that you can take any pointer with a non-void data type and use it like an array.
The main C file is pretty basic, just a couple function calls really.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {
  float myData[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f};

  puts("going to create matrix");
  matrix myMatrix = createMatrix(3, 3, myData);
  puts("matrix created");
  printf("Pointer to array of pointers:\n%p\n", myMatrix.data);

  puts("Pointers to rows:");
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < myMatrix.rows; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", myMatrix.data[i]);
  }

  puts("going to print matrix");
  printMatrix(myMatrix);
  puts("printed matrix");

  return 0;
 }
```

The actual matrix programming is in a header file:

```
//matrix.h
#pragma once

typedef struct matrix {
  int columns;
  int rows;
  float **data;
} matrix;

matrix createMatrix(int columns, int rows, float initialData[]) {
  //allocate struct                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  matrix *newMatrix = malloc(matrix);
  if(newMatrix == NULL) puts("struct allocation failed");
  memset(newMatrix, 0, sizeof(*newMatrix));
  newMatrix -> columns = columns;
  newMatrix -> rows = rows;

  //create initial data if none is given                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  if(initialData == NULL) {
    initialData = malloc(sizeof(float) * columns * rows);
    if(initialData == NULL) puts("Array allocation for initial data failed");
    memset(initialData, 0, sizeof(*initialData) * columns * rows);
  }

  //get the elements of each row                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  float **rowPointers;
  rowPointers = malloc(sizeof(float) * rows);
  if(rowPointers == NULL) puts("Array allocation for pointers failed");
  memset(rowPointers, 0, sizeof(float) * rows);
  float *rowData;
  int i;
  int j;

  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    printf("On row: %i\n", i + 1);
    //allocate data to store row data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    rowData = malloc(sizeof(*rowData) * columns); //create array for row and record pointer                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if(rowData == NULL) printf("Array allocation for matrix row %i failed", i + 1);
    memset(rowData, 0, sizeof(*rowData) * columns);
    rowPointers[i] = rowData; //store pointer to row data                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      rowData[j] = initialData[(i * columns) + j];
      printf("%f ", rowPointers[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  newMatrix -> data = rowPointers;

  return *newMatrix;
}

void printMatrix(matrix matrix) {
  printf("Confirming pointer to array of pointers:\n%p\n", matrix.data);
  int i;
  puts("Confirming pointers to rows:");
  for(i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", matrix.data[i]);
  }
  int j;

  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
    printf("On row: %i\n", i + 1);
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
      printf("%f ", matrix.data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

So far, nearly everything works. Everything involved in creating the matrix works. I can even print most of the data in the matrix. **Most** of the data. Running the code gives the output:

```
going to create matrix
On row: 1
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
On row: 2
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000
On row: 3
7.000000 8.000000 9.000000
matrix created
Pointer to array of pointers:
0x7f9a9ad00020
Pointers to rows:
0x7f9a9ad00030
0x7f9a9ad000e0
0x7f9a9ad000f0
going to print matrix
Confirming pointer to array of pointers:
0x7f9a9ad00020
Confirming pointers to rows:
0x7f9a9ad00030
0x7f9a9ad000e0
0x7f9a9ad000f0
On row: 1
-0.000000 0.000000 3.000000
On row: 2
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000
On row: 3
7.000000 8.000000 9.000000
printed matrix
```

As you can see, everything in rows 2 and 3 print correctly, and even columns 3 in row 1 prints correctly. I find it strange that in row 1 columns 1 and 2 don't come out right but column 3 does. If you look at the pointers to the rows, you'll notice that in memory row 1 is much farther from row 2 than row 2 is to row 3. Everytime I run this that is the case. Row 1 is always 0x70 away from row 2, and row 2 is always 0x10 away from row 2.
What isn't consistent is the data at row 1 columns 1. It is not always -0. Sometimes it is a very large number, other times a very small number. The data at row 1 column 2 is always 0 though.
Example of other outputs:

```
On row: 1
1704328922398720.000000 0.000000 3.000000
On row: 2
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000
On row: 3
7.000000 8.000000 9.000000
printed matrix
```

I have been unable to solve this problem and have no idea as to what is causing it given all of the info in the print statements. Why do the first two elements in the matrix print wrong and why is row 1 always so far away from row 2 in memory?

Comment: @Meninx I defined it as a float ** data, not a float (* data)[]. I am able to use it like an array though. Doing data[1] just retrieves the a float* sized data from ram at the address 'data' points to + the size of 1 float*. At least, that is how I understand it.

Comment: Any particular reason to use a `float**` instead of a `float*` that points to an array of `float`s with `columns` * `rows` elements?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I wanted to be able to access the data using data[row][column] instead of data[row * totalColumns + columns]

Comment: Well, if that's worth the extra memory allocation and complexity... Anyway, why allocate `initialData` if it's not given, only to use it to initialize the memory you've allocated for your floats? You are not `free`ing it, so that's a memory leak. Just `memset` `rowData` if there's no initial data given, or initialize it (no need for `memset` then) if there is initial data.

Comment: You may try `matrix *newMatrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix));` and then `newMatrix->data=malloc(sizeof(float*) * rows)`

Comment: @Pierter That is a good point. I do know there is a memory leak. I haven't dealt with it yet because I am not too worried about crashing an 8GB RAM computer by leaking 9 floats per run. Regarding  allocating initialData though, I will change that to make it more efficient. I am fairly new C, that is probably why I didn't notice that.

Comment: Are you running any other code besides what you've shown here - something that could overwrite memory it's not supposed to access? (Also, if I'm not mistaken, `malloc`ing a struct and returning it by value will cause a copy to be returned, and will leak the `malloc`ed instance. The `data` pointer of both instances will point to the same address however so it shouldn't cause such cell value corruption...)

Comment: @PieterWitvoet There is no other code being run. Someone gave an answer that pointed out I was allocating space for the pointer array in the struct, then I allocate room for it somewhere else and store it there, leaving extra space in my struct. That might be the problem.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet After changing the code as the answer said, I still am having the strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem after messing around with the code a lot.
I switched around rows and columns after I realized that elements of the matrix had to be accessed by `matrix.data[y][x]` instead of `matrix.data[x][y]`. I found a few places where columns and rows were mixed up, but in a 3x3 matrix, it wouldn't make a difference.
I changed the whole way the struct was created. I stopped using malloc to allocate it first and then fill it in with data and instead did this:
`newMatrix {columns, rows, malloc(sizeof(float*) * columns)};`
I was using malloc to allocate the struct before because I was making room for the pointer array in my struct, but malloc will allocate room somewhere random and give me the pointer to where it allocated memory. I think I was confused on the line between pointers and arrays.
I also am using `newMatrix.data` to refer to the pointer array instead of creating the array `rowData[rows]` and then storing the pointer to row data in `newMatrix.data`. I think I was confusing pointers and arrays again there.
Because I changed around rows and columns, the pointers in the array `matrix.data` points to do not point to arrays for the row data, but for the columns now.
`matrix.h` became this after fixing it:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct matrix {
  int columns;
  int rows;
  float **data;
} matrix;

matrix createMatrix(int columns, int rows, float initialData[]) {
  //create struct struct                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  matrix newMatrix = {
    columns,
    rows,
    malloc(sizeof(float*) * columns) //create array of pointers and store the pointer to it
  };

  if(newMatrix.data == NULL) puts("pointer array allocation failed");
  memset(newMatrix.data, 0, sizeof(float*) * columns);

  //create initial data if none is given                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  if(initialData == NULL) {
    initialData = malloc(sizeof(float) * columns * rows);
    if(initialData == NULL) puts("Array allocation for initial data failed");
    memset(initialData, 0, sizeof(float) * columns * rows);
  }

  //get the elements of each column                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  float *columnData;
  int i;
  int j;

  for(i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    printf("On column: %i\n", i + 1);
    //allocate data to store column data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    columnData = malloc(sizeof(float) * rows); //create array for column and record pointer                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if(columnData == NULL) printf("Array allocation for matrix column %i failed", i + 1);
    memset(columnData, 0, sizeof(float) * rows);
    newMatrix.data[i] = columnData; //store pointer to column data                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      columnData[j] = initialData[(j * columns) + i];
      printf("%f ", newMatrix.data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return newMatrix;
}

void printMatrix(matrix matrix) {
  printf("Confirming pointer to array of pointers:\n%p\n", matrix.data);
  int i;
  puts("Confirming pointers to columns:");
  for(i = 0; i < matrix.columns; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", matrix.data[i]);
  }
  int j;

  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
    printf("On row: %i\n", i + 1);
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++) {
      printf("%f ", matrix.data[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Note that I still have yet to deallocate the matrix and to fix the memory leak that is caused when I allocate `initialData` if `NULL` is passed, but that wasn't part of the question.
The only line that changed in the main file was:

```
for(i = 0; i < myMatrix.rows; i++) {
```

It changed to:

```
for(i = 0; i < myMatrix.columns; i++) {
```

In memory, column 1 still is farther away from column 2 than 2 is to 3, and I still don't know why, but it isn't affecting my code. The problem with accessing elements of the matrix was just the product me confusing arrays and pointers and making things messy as I try to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` may contain padding between members to maintain memory alignment.  This means the size of a `struct` is not always the same as the sum of the sizes of its members.

So, in `createMatrix()`, this line:

```
matrix *newMatrix = malloc((sizeof(int) * 2) + (sizeof(float*) * rows));
```

...should be:

```
matrix *newMatrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
```

Also note that you're `float **` is already part of the `matrix` type, and the
array of `float *` it points to is dynamically allocated later, so you don't need
to add extra space for the row pointers here.

---

The `memset()` after you allocate `initialData` when `NULL` was passed is only zeroing the first row -- should change it to:

```
  memset(initialData, 0, sizeof(*initialData) * rows * columns);
```

---

When you allocate the array of row pointers, you calculate the size with the wrong type.  So this:

```
rowPointers = malloc(sizeof(float) * columns);
```

should be:

```
rowPointers = malloc(sizeof(float *) * rows);
```

and the following memset should change to:

```
memset(rowPointers, 0, sizeof(float *) * rows);
```

---

Additionally, in `createMatrix()`, you should `free(initialData)` ***if*** you allocated it in the function (ie. if `NULL` was passed).  And remember that when freeing your `matrix` objects, you'll need to loop through and `free()` each row, then the row array, then the actual `matrix` struct -- so you may wish to write a function just for that.

You're also leaking memory by returning the `matrix` struct by value after dynamically allocating it inside `createMatrix` -- so the `malloc()`ed struct is leaked though the contents are copied for the return.  To fix it, you should either return a pointer to the dynamically allocated struct instead, or modify the function to use a local `matrix` variable instead of a dynamically allocated one.  To do this with minimal changes to your code, you could use this:

```
matrix newMatrixStruct;
matrix *newMatrix = &newMatrixStruct;
```

instead of the line that declares and `malloc()`s `newMatrix`.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it. I didn't know about the padding in structs. I am aware of the memory leak, not the one initialData caused though.

Comment: Hmm...still giving the same problem after the changes.

Comment: @Znapi Are you including `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and `string.h` in or before `matrix.h`?

Comment: I am including all of that except string.h.